# What does the first operand on var __decorator = (this && this.__decorate) || function() {...} try to do?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

When TypeScript decorator (class-decorator) gets transpiled to JavaScript it yields this:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
```

Now, what gets assigned to `var __decorate` variable when the `(this && this.__decorate)` returns `true`?

Also, if it gets abandoned how does it affect the whole code?

Comment: The expression `somethingTruthy || <anything>` resolves to the expression `somethingTruthy`, so it'd be `this.__decorate`

Comment: Please don't use quote markup unless quoting something. Also, boldface should be used only sparingly, and inline code markup should be used consistently.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know what the || operator will do but why then we need to include that first operand? What is it meant to avoid/prevent (as to the whole code i.e. when __decorate gets invoked)? *still puzzled but thx for respond,

Comment: Because otherwise, `this` isn't an object, so trying to access `this.__decorate` would throw

Comment: @CertainPerformance So the `this` will then be regarded as object if `_decorate` is assigned to the `function() {...}` Is that correct? Or if not how can `this` then be regarded as object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS does not nessesarily return `true` or `false` from a logical statement.  `A || B` will return A if it is truthy or B if A is falsy.  Similarly `A && B` will return A if it is falsy and B otherwise.

Both `||` and `&&` are also so-called short-circuit operators where the second operand is not even executed if it is not needed in order to determine the result.  So `(A && A.B)` is often used to get the value of `A.B` while guarding against  `A` being undefined, or `A = B || C` used to set `A` to `B` if it is defined, or to declare the definition `C` if it is not.

See, for example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for more details.

`(this && this._decorate)` looks like it is checking if `_decorate` is already defined on `this`.  First it is checking if `this` is defined (otherwise an error would be thrown) then checking the value.  If `this._decorate` is already defined then the function declaration will be skipped (as the existing `this._decorate` function will be truthy as all functions are).

The only JS operator which is guaranteed to return an actual boolean value is the not operator `!`.

Comment: `A || B` will return `A` if it's _truthy_, and `B` otherwise

Comment: Happens to the best of us.